“Unable to Access My Ubuntu Server from Other Devices on the Same Network – Need Help!”
I’ve been trying to set up a server on my Ubuntu machine to serve a frontend application built with Next.js, but I’m unable to access it from other devices on the same network. Here’s the setup and what I’ve tried so far:
My Setup:

OS: Ubuntu Linux
Frontend Framework: Next.js
Static File Server: serve (installed globally via npm)
IP Address: 192.168.0.46 (confirmed with ip addr show)
Port: Initially 3000, but serve picked port 45385 because 3000 was already in use.
Firewall: ufw is inactive (confirmed with sudo ufw status).

What Works:

I can access the app locally on the server itself using http://localhost:45385.
The server logs show incoming requests from another device, but they return 404 errors (e.g., for / and /favicon.ico).

What I’ve Tried:

Confirmed Server is Running:

• I started the frontend app using serve -s out -l 3000.
• Since port 3000 was in use, serve switched to 45385, and I used that port.

Checked IP and Network:

• Confirmed my server IP is 192.168.0.46.
• All devices (server and others) are on the same network.

Pinged the Server:

• I can successfully ping the server from other devices on the network.

Checked Router Settings:

• No client/device isolation mode is enabled on the router.

Firewall:

• ufw is inactive, but I still allowed traffic on port 3000 with sudo ufw allow 3000.

Rebuilt the Frontend:

• Ran npm run build followed by npm run export to ensure static files are correctly generated in the out directory.

Verified Static Files:

• The out directory contains files, but I still get a 404 error when accessing the app from other devices.

Checked Listening Ports:

• Ran netstat -tuln | grep 45385, and it confirmed the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:45385.
The Issue:

When I try to access http://192.168.0.46:45385 from another device, I
see a 404 error in the server logs for requests like GET / and GET
/favicon.ico.

My Questions:

Why would the server return a 404 for valid requests from other devices but work locally?

Is there anything I’m missing in terms of serving static files with serve?

Do I need to configure something else in Next.js or serve to make it accessible externally?


Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. I’ve been stuck on this for a while, and I feel like I’m missing something small but important.
Thanks in advance!
